# Date_trunc function when to use?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Figure out when to use date_trunc function for dates in the following example

I tried this code

```
SELECT
  -- Select eatery and calculate total cost
  eatery,
  DATE_TRUNC('month', stocking_date) :: DATE AS delivr_month,
  sum(meal_cost) :: FLOAT AS cost
FROM meals
JOIN stock ON meals.meal_id = stock.meal_id
-- Keep only the records after October 2018
WHERE stocking_date>'2018-10-01'
GROUP BY eatery, delivr_month
ORDER BY eatery, delivr_month;
```

But the correct answer is below and I don't understand why we need to use date_trunc function here as the query was able to run without it

```
SELECT
  -- Select eatery and calculate total cost
  eatery,
  DATE_TRUNC('month', stocking_date) :: DATE AS delivr_month,
  SUM(meal_cost * stocked_quantity) :: FLOAT AS cost
FROM meals
JOIN stock ON meals.meal_id = stock.meal_id
-- Keep only the records after October 2018
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('month', stocking_date) > '2018-10-01'
GROUP BY eatery, delivr_month
ORDER BY eatery, delivr_month;
```

Comment: You don’t need date_trunc() in the where condition.  Unless you have an index that also uses this function

Comment: What is the type for `stocking_date`?

Comment: I am not sure what is the data type of stocking_date. It wasn't mentioned.

Comment: 1) If you are using `psql` then `\d meals` and `\d stock` will provide that information. 2) Knowing the structure of the tables you are working with solves a  lot of issues.

Comment: If you are not using `psql` or do not have prgram that shows you the structure then this query will help: `select attname, atttypid::regtype from pg_class AS c join pg_attribute AS a on c.oid = a.attrelid where relname = <table_name> and attnum > 0;`. Where you substitute the actual 'table name' for `<table_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 1- `WHERE stocking_date>'2018-10-01'` and 2- `WHERE DATE_TRUNC('month', stocking_date) > '2018-10-01'` is:

The first one will show records that are from the date 2018-10-02, so there will be records from October 2018 while the commit says Keep only the records after October 2018.

The second one which use DATE_TRUNC will tranc any date to the first day of the month. for example 2018-10-15 will be 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-30 also will be 2018-10-01. and while the condition is > '2018-10-01' then all dates in the month October will not be shown in the result.